# Form a string in typescript with all attendees in Google Calendar API

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create an event using Google Calendar API using HTTP method.I am writing all my code in typescript.
Now, I have an array containing the email ids of all the attendees that we want to add to that event. So, to pass all those email ids of the attendees in a single query parameter, I am trying to form a single string in the exact format as that shown in API docs. But after forming the string, when I make the API request from server side code, it somehow passes unwanted backslash in that string.

I have tried forming a string by concatenating the keyword **email** which is to be sent in front of every email that I want to include as attendee. I tried using single backslash () as an escape sequence to insert double-inverted commas, but it didnt work.

I have also tried doing the same thing using **join()** function, but still unwanted backslashes get introduced in the string when I passed it as **attendee** parameter value in Create Event API call.

The expected format of string I need to pass in the API call is :

```
"attendees": [
    {
      "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
    },
{
       "email" : "abc@gmail.com"
}
]
```

The function I am trying to form the string is -

```
for (let index = 0; index < email_ids.length-1; index++) {
                    mapping = mapping + "{'email':"+"'"+email_ids[index]+"'}";
                    if((email_ids.length-1)!=index) {
                       mapping=mapping+ ",";
                    }
                }
```

Here **mapping** is the string I am trying to form. 
Now the problem is when I console.log this **mapping** string, it prints something like -

```
{'email': " xyz@gmail.com '} , {'email': " abc@gmail.com '}
```

which is exactly something I want to pass inside the **attendee** parameter. But when I read the logs of the API request that I sent, I see the parameter **attendee** to be something like -

```
"attendees":["{\'email\': \\" xyz@gmail.com \'} , {\'email\': \\" abc@gmail.com \'} "]
```

There are these unwanted backslashes that get introduced at every point of concatenation in my above function, and I want to remove these. I think this is the reason why I am creating a public event but it isn't adding the attendees to that event, so this adding attendees part is not working as expected.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you're using the client library, pass an object not a string.  Look at the example here:  https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events

Comment: I am actually not using any client library, just directly making a POST request as mentioned here - https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be generating a string, and passing this back to whatever method is sending the data. Like Dan D said in a comment, try creating an object instead, as it seems that's what the interface is expecting in the `atendees[]` field.

This also simplifies your code a lot:

```
const list = email_ids.map((id: string) => ({ email: id }));
```

This creates a full list. In on your code you skip the last item in `email_ids`. I'm assuming it's an error, but if not, you can do it this way:

```
const list = email_ids
   .filter((_:string, i:number)=> i < email_ids.length -1)
   .map((id: string) => ({ email: id }));
```

This will generate an `Array` with the objects, as in

```
[
  { email: "xyz@gmail.com" },
  { email: "abc@gmail.com" }
]
```

Also, notice your code seems to be transforming the data into an array somewhere already:

```
"attendees":["..."]
```

So to avoid an array inside of an array, you'll need to figure out what's going on and how to pass/receive the correct data. It's hard to say without looking at the whole lifecycle of that payload from generation to sending to the server.

Lastly: in general, there's no reason to generate JSON by hand. In fact, I can't think of a single reason where anyone would ever want or need to create a JSON source code directly. If you really need a `string` rather than ab object, creating an object (like above) and calling `JSON.stringify()` on it later is the right solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. It is actually correct. I still needed to form the whole mapping but instead of passing a whole array, I was thus passing a string. So I needed to make 2 changes - while mapping the word "email" to ids, I was forming a string which should have been an object, just like you said, and second was to pass the whole mapping array (which is formed in required format)instead of a string. That did the trick for me!